# why doesn't work the else-branch with the set()-method?

Tags: if-statement, methods, processing

Link to my sketch:
http://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/377417

```java
void check(ship s){
float d = dist(s.getX(),s.getY(),this.posx,this.posy);
if (d <= this.radius){
s.setSpeed(0.5);
}
if (d > this.radius){
s.setSpeed(2);
}
}
```

When i delete the second if-statement, the ship reduces its speed but don't accelerate when the distance is greater than the obstacle's radius.

Something's wrong with the set-method?

Answer (score 0):

In the future, please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) directly in your post instead of making us go to external websites. Also, please use standard naming conventions: classes should start with an upper-case letter. While you're at it, standard formatting (indent your code) would help too.

That being said, your problem is caused by this: think about how you're calling your `check()` function. You call it for every obstacle. Then you set the speed of the ship based on the distance from that obstacle.

The problem is, say you only have two obstacles. The first obstacle is colliding with the ship, so you set its speed to `0.5`. Then you check the second obstacle, which isn't colliding with the ship, so you set its speed back up to `2`. In other words, **you're only ever changing the ship's speed based on the last `obstacle` in the loop**.

If you take out the call to `setSpeed(2)`, then of course your ship will never change speed back to `2`.

You need to refactor your code so that you set the speed to `0.5` if the ship is colliding with **any** obstacle. It might look something like this:

```java
boolean collides = false;
for(Obstacle o : obstacles){
   if(o.collidesWith(ship)){
      collides = true;
      break;
   }
}
if(collides){
   ship.setSpeed(.5);
}
else{
   ship.setSpeed(2);
}
```